# My app opens index.html instead of index.jsx

Tags: html, reactjs, npm, jsx, delete-file

I created a page using `React.jsx`, and when I typed `npm start` the page opened `index.jsx`. However, I deleted index.html and then restored it to " public ", since then my page no longer opens `index.jsx`, but now it opens index.html (so the result is a white page, which when I write  hello < /h1> changes. I would like to know if there is a solution for this problem...
My json package if it's useful:

```json
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start-build": "npm run start & npm run build",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "gh-pages": "^5.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

I tried deleting the `node_modules` file and the `package-lock.json` file, and then I used `npm install` to reinstall, but it didn't work

Comment: What does your `index.html` file look like? It seems like it was doing things before that it isn't doing now, as far as I know the normal behaviour is that react scripts opens index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open index.jsx instead of index.html when running npm start in your React app, you need to make sure that the start script in your package.json file is pointing to the correct file.

Open your package.json file.
Find the "scripts" object.
Look for the "start" property and make sure it points to your index.jsx file.
For example, if your index.jsx file is in a folder called src, the "start" property should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start src/index.jsx",
// other scripts
}
```

Save the changes and try running npm start again. This should open your React app with index.jsx as the entry point

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately doing this process that you suggested me, it keeps opening an html page and not jsx, do you know something about babel and if it can be a good solution?

Comment: The issue may be related to the default configuration of create-react-app. By default, create-react-app serves the index.html file located in the public folder. Try to update the index.js file inside the src folder to render your index.jsx component. Inside index.js try this:

    `import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import App from './index.jsx';`

And try to replace ReactDom render call:

     `ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
     <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
    );`

I hope this can fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I hope it helps other people who had the same problem I had. But I tried another solution, changed my code from jsx to tsx, and installed webpack. But I'm not sure if that solved the problem, the truth is I kept having the same problem, then I found that when I didn't use route, my code worked, so I installed route6 and removed <Navbar/> from inside Route and put it below < BrowserRouter>, the page is not like before, but let's say after a week I'm on a good road. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Finally I got it fixed, I just had to add <Router basename="/MyURL"> and now everything works perfectly, I'll have long afternoons uninstalling all sorts of things that I researched and claimed to be a solution

Comment: I am glad that you found the solution and shared here. Thanks